# Jenkins Pipeline Send email with an attachment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to send an email with attachment using the **emailextension**. I am not seeing the attachment in the mail.

How to resolve this?

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: '/scratch/testuser/output.html', body: "Test", mimeType: 'text/html',  subject: 's1', to: "${EMAIL_LIST}"
```

Comment: Does changing to ant like pattern helps ?, like in : `'**/output.html'`

Answer (score -1):

```
     emailext attachmentsPattern: 'attachment.html',
     body: "test",
     recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor()],
     subject: "testattachment: Job test"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25366875)

Comment: @hivert This "not an answer" flag/comment is for answers that don't even attempt to answer the question. This one does, albeit that an explanation would greatly increase its value.

Comment: Thanks for this input. Could you please share the logic for "mail to" also.